# recursive function that iterates through a list of tuples (int * int) and adds the second value

Tags: list, tuples, ocaml

I want to write a function that iterates through a list of tuples (int * int) and adds the second value of the tuple if the first value of the tuple is the int 0. I came up with the following code however, it raises exception for every case, could anyone point out what is the error in the function? Thanks in advance!

```
let rec tup x = match x with (a,b)::t -> if a > 0 then b + tup(t) else 0 + tup(t) | []->failwith("a");;    

test case: (int * int) list = [(0, 2); (1, 10); (0, 20)] should return 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You designed this function as recursive, so its last call will always match with `[]`. If you change `failwith("a")` to `0` function works as expected:

```
let rec tup x = match x with 
    (a,b)::t -> if a > 0 then b + tup(t) else tup(t) 
    | [] -> 0
;;
```

Results:

```
# tup [(0,2); (1,10); (0,20)];;
- : int = 10
# tup [(3,4); (1,10); (0,20)];;
- : int = 14
# tup [];;  (* You don't want to fail in this case *)
- : int = 0
```